# streaming a video from website android

Tags: android, android-video-player, android-videoview

I am new to android.

I have created a simple example for playing video files with the videoView.
the xml part contains only one Button and a VideoView,
Here is the code for ButtonClick

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.learnixmba.com/doajax.php?profile=2809");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
            startActivity(intent);

        }
```

when I try running this app on Emulator I am getting error message as "Cant Play Video"
Why I am getting this message and the logcat shows one error as

```
12-30 05:25:37.623: E/cutils-trace(1370): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

need answers and advises
Thanks in advance

edit:

I tried loading this same video url to a webView.,
and it shows...,

"some of your technology may be out of date this video may not play properly"

what is the problem ? am I using outdated tools??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide a direct link to your video.

Try to change this line:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.learnixmba.com/doajax.php?profile=2809");
```

To this:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://pdl.vimeocdn.com/01593/020/145269025.mp4?token2=1388403392_f17d62baae773f48f5b1565a69857345&amp;aksessionid=1ba8f3ac4cafca62");
```

EDIT:
DISPLAY YOUTUBE VIDEOS

```
String videoId = "0HDsz3C9IHg"; // id of the youtube video you want to display
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"+videoId)); 
intent.putExtra("VIDEO_ID", videoId); 
startActivity(intent);
```

OR DIRECT LINK TO VIDEO, PLAYING IN THE YOUTUBE PLAYER:

```
Intent videoClient = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
videoClient.setData("VALID YOUTUBE LINK WITH HTTP");
videoClient.setClassName("com.google.android.youtube","com.google.android.youtube.WatchActivity");
startActivity(videoClient);
```

Comment: Thanks But ...,:-(  _Still not working!!_..., Where did you get that direct link from? can I use **Youtube** Links like this to stream Youtube Videos??

Comment: in the html code, it is better if you use youtube link video, I'll update my answer for you to play youtube videos.

Comment: glad I could help. Happy new year! *